# asp.net mvc and javascript textbox issue

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with the `TextBox`. When I was entering duplicate data, it is not allowing. That is what exactly I need but after saving data again it is allowing the duplicate data. How can I handle the scenario?

Here is my code.

```
var Controls = {
    saveObjectives: function (actionurl) {
        var frm = $('form[name=frmObjectives]')
        frm.attr('action', actionurl);
        frm.submit();
    },
    addObjectiveCheckbox: function () {
        var text = $('#txtObjective').val();
        $('#txtObjective').val('');
        if ($.trim(text) == '')
            return;
        if ($('input[type=checkbox][value="' + text + '"]').length == 0)
        $('#dvObjectives').prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="chkNewobjectives" value="' + text + '" Checked /> ' + text + '<br />');
    },
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<input id="btnAddObj" class="btn" type="button" onclick="Controls.addObjectiveCheckbox();" value="Add Objective"/>
      </div> 
    <div id="dvObjectives" name="ObjectivesList">

    @foreach (Andromeda.Core.Entities.Objectives objective in Model)
    {
        <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkobjectives" Checked value="@objective.ObjectiveID" />@objective.ObjectiveText
        </label>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try to formulate your question a bit better? I don't think I understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using value='whatever text` in the jQuery, but value='ObjectiveID' in the view.  This should fix it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkobjectives" Checked value="@objective.ObjectiveText" />@objective.ObjectiveText
```

Comment: What does the generated html look like from the code I suggested above look like?